# Python-Wand Sequence Not Clearing From Memory

Tags: imagemagick, wand

If I do the following

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
  for myFile in files:
    with Image(filename=myFile) as img:
      with Image(image=img) as main:
        print main.sequence[0].width
```

I end up with memory faults using Wand.

I'm sure its the .sequence part.  If I remove that, its fine.  I've read all I can find on sequence, how its an Image vs SingleImage.

The SingleImage sequence part stays in memory. I've tried to use the following:

```py
main.sequence[0].destroy()
```

but it does not get rid of the image in the memory.

I'm processing thousands of files, but after just a few dozen I get segmentation faults.

I'm pretty sure its closing the 'main' Image.  Just not the main.sequence SingleImage.

Is there a way to forcibly close that?

I should say I've also tried this

```py
with Image(image=img.sequence[0]) as main:
```

thinking the With statement would close it indirectly.  But it does not.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You may reference to an answer here for some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209861/how-to-reduce-wand-memory-usage

Answer (score 1):

First things first - file a [bug with wand](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues). The `wand.image.Image.destroy` is not cleaning up `wand.image.Sequence` in the event an image sequence was allocated. *Good find!*

You are absolutely correct with `main.sequence[0].destroy()`; however, your only freeing the first allocated `SingleImage` in the sequence. So `img.sequence[1:]` is still setting in memory. A not-so-elegant solution would be to iterate & destroy all `SingleImage`'s.

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
  for myFile in files:
    with Image(filename=myFile) as img:
      with Image(image=img) as main:
        first = True
        for frame in main.sequence:
           if first:
             print frame.width
             first = False
           frame.destroy()
```

*comment:* Reading an image from file to `img`, copying the data to `main`, and creating sub-images in a sequence seems very memory intensive. I'm sure your doing a lot more than identifying the image width, but can that be rewritten? Imagemagick does have a [ping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#identify_ping) method ( not yet implemented in `wand` ) which doesn't read image data into memory.

Comment: I can try to file a bug report.  However you workaround does not work. Even if I try to destroy each one individually, I still get huge memory use.

It appears I didn't initially notice this, because once you hit the limit of your RAM, it starts to store images in /tmp. It wasn't until I ran out of disk space that I discovered this problem.

Anyway, is there a way to destroy ALL open images (Images and SingleImages) currently open. I could just 'refresh/restart' at each loop. It works if I restart the script, how can I clear everything from the script at the start of each loop?

Comment: @Nertskull Did you find a way?