# How to reduce wand memory usage?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, wand, python-tesseract

I am using wand and pytesseract to get the text of pdfs uploaded to a django website like so:

```
image_pdf = Image(blob=read_pdf_file, resolution=300)
image_png = image_pdf.convert('png')

req_image = []
final_text = []

for img in image_png.sequence:
    img_page = Image(image=img)
    req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('png'))

for img in req_image:
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)).convert('RGB'))
    final_text.append(txt)

return " ".join(final_text)
```

I have it running in celery in a separate ec2 server. However, because the image_pdf grows to approximately 4gb for even a 13.7 mb pdf file, it is being stopped by the oom killer. Instead of paying for higher ram, I want to try to reduce the memory used by wand and ImageMagick. Since it is already async I don't mind increased computation times. I have skimmed this: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive, but am not sure if it can be implemented with wand. Another possible fix is a way to open a pdf in wand one page at a time rather than putting the full image into RAM at once. Alternatively, how could I interface with ImageMagick directly using python so that I could use these memory limiting techniques?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library integrates with `MagickWand` API, and in turn, delegates PDF encoding/decoding work to `ghostscript`. Both `MagickWand` & `ghostscript` allocated additional memory resources, and do there best to deallocate at the end of each task. However, if routines are initialized by python, and held by a variable, it's more than possible to introduce memory-leaks.

Here's some tips to ensure memory is managed correctly.

1. Use `with` context management for all Wand assignments. This will ensure all resources pass through `__enter__` & `__exit__` management handlers.
2. Avoid `blob` creation for passing data. When creating a file-format blob, MagickWand will allocated additional memory to copy & encode the image, and python will hold resulting data in addition to the originating wand instance. Usually fine on the dev environment, but can grow out of hand quickly in a production setting.
3. Avoid `Image.sequence`. This is another copy-heavy routine, and results in python holding a bunch of memory resources. Remember ImageMagick manages the image stacks very well, so if you're not reordering / manipulating individual frames, it's best to use MagickWand methods & not involve python.
4. Each task should be an isolated process, and can cleanly shut-down on completion. This shouldn't be an issue for you w/ `celery` as a queue worker, but worth double checking the thread/worker configuration + docs.
5. Watch out for resolution. A pdf resolution of 300 @ 16Q would result in a massive raster image. With many OCR (tesseract/opencv) techniques, the first step is to pre-process the inbound data to *remove* extra/unneeded colors / channels / data / &tc.

Here's an example of how I would approach this. Note, I'll leverage [ctypes](/questions/tagged/ctypes) to directly manage the image stack w/o additional python resources.

```py
import ctyles
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Tell wand about C-API method
library.MagickNextImage.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
library.MagickNextImage.restype = ctypes.c_int

# ... Skip to calling method ...

final_text = []
with Image(blob=read_pdf_file, resolution=100) as context:
    context.depth = 8
    library.MagickResetIterator(context.wand)
    while(library.MagickNextImage(context.wand) != 0):
        data = context.make_blob("RGB")
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(data)
        final_text.append(text)
return " ".join(final_text)
```

Of course your milage may vary. If your comfortable with [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess), you may be able to execute `gs` & `tesseract` directly, and eliminate all the python wrappers.

Comment: what is context here ?

Comment: Sharp eye! The `context` variable _should_ be an instance of `Image` object allocated by the `with` stack. I'll update the example.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but then pytesseract expects pillow Image object and so throws `TypeError: Unsupported image object`

Comment: This answer address memory usage with Wand library, and not pillow/pytesseract API. I can't speak for those python modules, but I can comment that `Tesseract` uses `Leptonica` as it's raster I/O, so you can eliminate `pillow`, `PIL`, `pytesseract`, `Wand`, & `ImageMagick` entirely. The [documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample#c-api-in-python) shows you how, and the internet is full of [examples](https://github.com/emcconville/sutocr/blob/master/sutocr/helpers.py#L58).

Comment: You said avoid Image.sequence, does "while" loop through the sequence of images?

Answer (score 1):

I was also suffering from memory leaks issues. After some research and tweaking the code implementation, my issues were resolved.
I basically worked correctly using **with** and **destroy()** function.

In some cases I could use  **with**  to open and read the files, as in the example below:

```
with Image(filename = pdf_file, resolution = 300) as pdf:
```

This case, using with, the memory and tmp files are correctly managed.

And in another case I had to use the **destroy()** function, preferably inside a **try / finally** block, as below:

```
try:
    for img in pdfImg.sequence:
    # your code
finally:
    pdfImg.destroy()
```

The second case, is an example where I cann't use **with** because I had to iterate the pages through the **sequence**, so, I already had the file open and was iterating your pages.

This conbination of solution resolved my problems with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The code from @emcconville works, and my temp folder is not filling up with magick-* files anymore

I needed to Import ctypes and not cstyles

I also got the error mentioned by @kerthik

solved it by saving the image and loading it again, it is properly also possible to save it to memory

```
from PIL import Image as PILImage

...
context.save(filename="temp.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(PILImage.open("temp.jpg"))`
```

EDIT
I found the in memory conversion on [How to convert wand.image.Image to PIL.Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536843/how-to-convert-wand-image-image-to-pil-image)

```
img_buffer = np.asarray(bytearray(context.make_blob(format='png')),dtype='uint8')
bytesio = io.BytesIO(img_buffer)
text = ytesseract.image_to_string(PILImage.open(bytesio),lang="dan")
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue.

Found this page interesting: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel

And how to limit the amount of memory used by ImageMagick through wand:
http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/resource.html

Just adding something like:

```
from wand.resource import limits

# Use 100MB of ram before writing temp data to disk.
limits['memory'] = 1024 * 1024 * 100
```

It may increase the computation time (but like you, I don't mind too much) and I actually did not notice so much difference.

I confirmed using Python's [memory-profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) that it is working as expected.