# How to convert wand.image.Image to PIL.Image?

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-imaging-library, wand

I spent whole day on this problem and did not see answer in stack overflow!

I tried this but did not work:

```
    >> pil_image = Image.frombytes('RGBA', wand_image.size, wand_image.make_blob(format='png'), 'raw')

    ValueError: not enough image data
```

I appreciate every solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```py
img_buffer = numpy.asarray(bytearray(wand_img.make_blob(format='png')), dtype='uint8')
bytesio = io.BytesIO(img_buffer)
pil_img = PIL.Image.open(bytesio)
```

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't involve numpy:

```
pil_image = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(wand_image.make_blob("png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is through numpy - meaning to export PIL image into numpy array and then read it by wand

```
from wand.image import Image
from IPython.display import display
with Image.from_array(np.array(img)) as ximg:
    display(ximg)
```

or the other way around

```
from wand.image import Image
from matplotlib import cm

with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    array = np.array(img)
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gist_earth(array)*255))
```

Comment: although it requires numpy, this solution is much faster than serialising the entire image in PNG format into a temporary buffer and then parsing the PNG structure again into a third buffer. i can't believe i'm the first person to upvote this since it was posted over a year ago!