# Python Wand Eating all available Disk Space on Mac when converting PDFs using OCR

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, ocr, wand

I believe this is my first StackOverflow question, so please be nice.

I am OCRing a repository of PDFs (~1GB in total) ranging from 50-200 pages each and found that suddenly all of the available 100GB of remaining harddrive space on my Macbook Pro were gone. Based on a previous post, it seems that ImageMagick is the culprit as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100956/python-wand-sequence-not-clearing-from-memory).

I found that these files are called 'magick-*' and are stored in /private/var/tmp. For only 23 PDFs it had created 3576 files totaling 181GB.

How can I delete these files immediately within the code after they are no longer needed? Thank you in advance for any suggestions to remedy this issue.

Here is the code:

```
import io, os
import json
import unicodedata
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
from wand.image import Image
from tqdm import tqdm

# Where you want to save the PDFs
destination_folder = 'contract_data/Contracts_Backlog/'


pdfs = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKC',f.decode('utf8')) for f in os.listdir(destination_folder) if f.lower().endswith('.pdf')]
txt_files = [unicodedata.normalize('NFKC',f.decode('utf8')) for f in os.listdir(destination_folder) if f.lower().endswith('.txt')]


### Perform OCR on PDFs
def ocr_pdf_to_text(filename):
    tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
    lang = 'spa'
    req_image = []
    final_text = []
    image_pdf = Image(filename=filename, resolution=300)
    image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')
    for img in image_jpeg.sequence:
        img_page = Image(image=img)
        req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('jpeg'))

    for img in req_image: 
        txt = tool.image_to_string(
            PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
            lang=lang,
            builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
        )
        final_text.append(txt)
    return final_text

for filename in tqdm(pdfs):
    txt_file = filename[:-3] +'txt'
    txt_filename = destination_folder + txt_file
    if not txt_file in txt_files: 
        print 'Converting ' + filename 
        try:
            ocr_txt = ocr_pdf_to_text(destination_folder + filename)
            with open(txt_filename,'w') as f:
                for i in range(len(ocr_txt)):
                    f.write(json.dumps({i:ocr_txt[i].encode('utf8')}))
                    f.write('\n')
            f.close()
        except:
            print "Could not OCR " + filename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky way of dealing with this was to add an os.remove() statement within the main loop to remove the tmp files after creation.

```
tempdir = '/private/var/tmp/'
files = os.listdir(tempdir)
    for file in files:
        if "magick" in file:
            os.remove(os.path.join(tempdir,file))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image` should be used as a context manager, because Wand determine timings to dispose resources including temporary files, in-memory buffers, and so on. `with` block help Wand to know boundaries when these `Image` objects are still needed and when they are now unnecessary.

See also the [official docs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/guide/resource.html).

Comment: Imagemagick should not leave any of its files in /tmp unless the command failed unexpectedly in the middle of processing, such as running out of space in /tmp or not enough memory. If the command finishes, then Imagemagick will/should automatically delete those files, unless it does not have correct privileges. Check your resource limits. Sorry I know little about Python Wand itself.

Comment: @fmw42 Of course Wand handles that as well. If Python process terminates due to runtime error or normally exits Wand disposes all resources it made. However, if Python process runs long, these resources cannot be disposed until the whole program ends. Using Wand images as context managers help to determine when the resources are okay to be disposed before the whole program ends.